# Override Native Alert Function of Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I want to override the alert function for a webpage.
The following code works for running on console.

```
window.alert = function(msg) {

    console.log("test succeed");

}
```

If I run the alert("test") command from console, the overrided alert function works, but I dont want to work with console. I want to change the real web page 's alert function. For examle I want to change https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert alert functions. Is it possible?

Comment: The same code you use in the browser's console, can be used either in a `<script>...</script>` tag or in a JS file. The override should work.

Comment: While your code does succeed in preventing someone (or you) from calling `alert()`, the browser's native alert function can't be changed. You can't style it, etc.

Comment: Did you try adding that code (`window.alert .... `) in the code you shared from `w3schools` ?

Comment: @MihaiT yes I have tried, but it did not work. I wonder whether it is possible with different aprroaches or not

Comment: It does work. `<script>
window.alert = function(msg) {

    console.log("test succeed");

}
function myFunction() {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>` But why would you want to do this ? Maybe there's another solution to your requirement

Comment: @MihaiT the web page only is an example, -I accept that it is not convenient example-. I will use it on different web pages whose source code can not be edited. for instance on amazon etc..

Comment: No, you cannot do that. I still don't understand why you need this though :)

Comment: @MihaiT I am trying to automatize a process. The process needs this task